# Mysql Query Not in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, psql

```
select * from tab1;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
+------+

select * from empt;
+------+------+------+
| id   | l1   | l2   |
+------+------+------+
|   10 |    1 |  100 |
|   11 |    1 |  101 |
|   12 |    1 |  102 |
|   13 |    2 |  100 |
|   14 |    4 |  101 |
+------+------+------+
```

L1 column in empt table is a foreign key for tab1.id.

I need the ID's of `tab1` which do not have `100` in `l2` Column

The Query which I tried but didn't get correct Result.

```
select tab1.id from tab1 left join empt on tab1.id = empt.l1
where l2 not in(100);
```

The Output what I want is

```
+------+
|tab1.id|
+------+
|    3 |
|    4 |
+------+
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: @jarlh Im using Both

Comment: It seems like you want 2,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.*  
           FROM tab1 x 
           LEFT 
           JOIN empt y 
             ON y.l1 = x.id 
            AND y.l2 IN(100) 
          WHERE y.l1 IS NULL;
```

Comment: This one returns 2 and 3 but i want 3 and 4

Comment: The IN is useless here

Comment: @DanielE You're mistaken. On a properly indexed table, it would make almost no difference.

Comment: @Strawberry Why should we use `y.l2 IN(100)` in `ON` Condition why not  in `Where` Condition.

Comment: @vinieth Why not try it and see?

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT id
FROM tab1
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT l1 FROM empt WHERE l2 = 100);`

Comment: This wont the give the result 3&4. Your query will give 1&4

Comment: Now it returns 2 and 3

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use left join a simple select Sql statement can resolve your problem :

```
select id from tab1 where id not in(select l1 from empt where l2 = 100)
```

Best regards

Comment: `Not IN` Can't Use Index

Answer (score 1):

use `NOT EXISTS`

```
select t1.id
from tab1 t1
where not exists(select 1 from empt t2 where t2.l1 = t1.id and t2.l2 = 100)
```

Comment: I can't use subquery. Is there any other way using join

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Distinct tab1.id
FROM tab1
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM empt WHERE empt.12 = 100) t on tab1.id = t.l1
WHERE t.l1 IS NULL
```

Comment: When I it has 1lakh rows  in temp table for Inner Join. The query will be very slow

Answer (score -1):

Add a group by to your query

```
select tab1.id 
from tab1 
    left join empt on tab1.id = empt.l1 
where l2 not in (100) 
group by tab1.id
```

Comment: GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved. How come?

Comment: This query will give output as 1&4.  But i want 3&4 as output

Comment: There is no problem for which this could be a valid solution.